# Installing FreeGlut 3.0.0 in Netbeans IDE with Cygwin Compiler

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, cygwin

I am trying to install freeglut and set up opengl within my netbeans 8.02 ide.
I am using the cygwin (gcc/g++) compiler in netbeans. I have already installed freeglut 3.0.0 but I don't know how to link together the freeglut libraries with the cygwin compiler in netbeans.

I think that I have to copy and paste the bin, lib, and include folders from freetglut and merge them with the bin, lib, and include folders within the cygwin folder. Im not too sure on this.

Comment: Also I thought that I might add that I do not see the bin and lib folders within the freeglut3.0.0 folder. However I do see the include folder and these other folders as well:

Comment: other folders: android, doc, progs, src. And then there are a bunch of files. I'd post a screenshot but my rep on here isn't high enough :<

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple comments:

1. It seems that free glut isn't compiled. There are probably included make files or CMake files included, build with that. If you are new to that, google it.
2. About making sure that Cygwin links to them, your suppose approach would work, but it is not the best. I suggest that you add the lib folder to your link (or library) directories in your IDE. I'm not familiar with net beans, but it is probably in your project settings page.
3. About your bin directory, I suggest copying the contents of that into your output directory for your .exe so that way when you redistribute your program your users are guaranteed  to have it.